# MySQL response times spiking at regular intervals

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, django, database-administration, bitnami

I recently set up a windows Hyper-V VPS with a bitnami django stack. I am monitering the website with newrelic. I noticed that my MySQL database response times spike about every 30 min. My first thought was that a cron job was running every 30 mins, but there are no crons on this server. So I have two questions:
In newrelic what is "Other - SQL" field?
What could be causing the database response time to spike?

See database performance graph at http://i.troll.ws/5bc7b010.PNG

Comment: Other-SQL seems to be any kind of query that newrelic doesn't know how to categorize.  Are you familiar with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`?

Comment: I was not familier with SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST. Why do you mention it? The output from this command is shown here: [cmd screenshot](http://i.troll.ws/eec8d10b.PNG)

Comment: It's a vital command for understanding what's going on with your server right at the moment when you run it... you can see all of the current connections, and the query they're currently running, and how long they've been doing it, while "Sleep" connections are idle, imposing no meaningful load.  You should be able to identify what's going on *by catching it in the act*, using that capability, and then identify what, if anything, needs to be changed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html ... checking it periodically should point you in a useful direction.